# Is it bad practice to output script tags in the middle of the page?

Tags: jquery

Merely out of convenience, I'm hoping to, using a server side language, just output a simple `<script>` tag with jquery's `document.ready()` function. Is this considered bad practice? I know some people consider inline javascript bad practice, which makes me wonder about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a problem from the technical point of view, because `document.ready()` will fire only after the DOM is fully parsed.

I wouldn't consider it good style, though. It can make maintenance hellishly difficult, because you can't see what's happening on document load at one glance any more.

I would aim to keep everything in one `document.ready()` block if at all possible, and that block in the `head` or even an external script file if at all possible.

Comment: Going with this, some things might not even work. Say, for instance, if you are writing out a script that does an immediate document.write("blah"). [I know this is dumb, but bear with me] Since the document has already been parsed, that line will not be interpreted, and the line not written out to the doc.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably not considered the best practice, but it will still work.  If you have some restriction that requires you to do this, then do it.  For me, making things work is **the** best practice.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional approach is to put javascript in between `<head></head>` tags. However, famous [Yahoo performance article](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) advocates it should be placed at the end of the page to gain some speed boost. See the section: ***Put Scripts at the Bottom***. And if I can remember, that turns out to be SEO-friendly as google also supports this approach if I can recall the article I had read.

As for functionality, even if  you put script tags in middle of the page but use appropriate events, your code will still work fine.

Comment: Exactly, Crockford advocates that, and he clearly states why: " It is better to call for the script as late as possible, so that the loading of images and other components will not be delayed." http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html